# error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS and wxWidgets 3.1.4. When I try executing the wxWidgets binary with:
`./gpCalculator`

I get the error message:
`./gpCalculator: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

**This is the output of** `ldd ./gpCalculator` **below**:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcabd9c000)
libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3 => not found
libwx_baseu-3.1.so.3 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007faa0bf17000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007faa0bcff000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa0b90e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007faa0b570000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faa0c524000)
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated. It's a school project. The gitub repo is https://github.com/alvindera97/Engineering-Grade-Pending-C-
if you would like to gain access to the binary itself and the source code.

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 4):

You have to install those libraries.

The error says are missing (can't be found.)

```
libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3 => not found
libwx_baseu-3.1.so.3 => not found
```

Install command:

`apt-get install libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5`

If you want to know which package provides a file, you can install and update (as root):

```
root@desktop:~# apt-get install apt-file
root@desktop:~# apt-file update
```

And find:

```
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ apt-file find wx_gtk3u

libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_media-3.0.so.0
libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_media-3.0.so.0.4.0
libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_media-3.0.so
libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so.0
libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so.0.4.0
libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so
```

Which gives you the packages: `libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5`, `libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev` in which that name appears.

If you are working with a compiled binary (a program) you have to install the libraries that were used to compile that program in the original linux install (same version or, often, more modern.)

If you can't install those, with Linux, at least, you can compile all from source: libs, program, etc...

(Explanations after some comments.)

In fact, you *are* working with the compiled program, and I have the exact same output:

```
 
manuel@desktop:~/projects/Engineering-Grade-Pending-C- (master)$ ./gpCalculator 
./gpCalculator: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Checking out the repo gives:

```
manuel@desktop:~/projects/Engineering-Grade-Pending-C- (master)$ l
total 8,1M
-rw-r--r-- 1 manuel manuel 230K jul 29 23:10 gp_and_cgpa_calculator.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel 597K jul 29 23:10 gpCalculator*
-rw-r--r-- 1 manuel manuel 7,3M jul 29 23:10 gpCalculator.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 manuel manuel 1,2K jul 29 23:10 README.md
```

were `gpCalculator` is the executable that can't find the libraries.

The problem, isn't in the compiling or distribution, the problem is that you *never should run* software from a source you don't know and trust. If you want to run this, just get the source, compile and use it.

This `gpCalculator` executable could be just sending all your hard drive information to anyone.

That being said, to run that program you just have to do what I said: *install* the missing libraries or *compile and install* all of them. (Don't need to distribute *anything*.)

Comment: This is the reply I got from the terminal:
`E: Unable to locate package libwx_gtk3u_core`

`E: Unable to locate package libwx_gtk3u_core`

Comment: @Alvindera97 yes, sorry, wrong lib names. Put your version numbers anyway, I work with an old system.

Comment: I tried running the command you added to the answer `apt-get install libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5 libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5` and I still got the same error message: `./gpCalculator: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I'm not sure how I'll be able to properly guess the version numbers, however, I have a wxWidgets install of version 3.1.4....

Comment: @Alvindera97 *version numbers*, I've put an example, your version numbers are different.

Comment: Thank you  so much. I'm working on it now. I'll get back to you as soon as it's done

Comment: `sudo apt-file find libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.so.3` returned nothing unfortunately. Same result with 'sudo apt-file find libwx_baseu-3.1.so.3'

Comment: @Alvindera97 Did you run `sudo apt-file update`? Also, do the search without version numbers to look for all libraries with that name `sudo apt-file find libwx_gtk3u_core`.

Comment: At this point, I don't know if it would still be possible to run the same app. Since I have the source code and an install of wxWidgets, I was able to recompile the binary into a new file and run the program, **The source code was written and compiled with wxWidgets3.1.3** however I have **wxWidgets3.1.4 installed** and I am not trying to recompile. I am only trying to run the binary. 

If I wanted to run this program on another linux install, does this mean that I have to reinstall wxWidgets and recompile the program? I am really perplexed.

Thank you.

Comment: @Alvindera97 you have to install the libraries that were used to compile that program in the other linux install. If you can't, you can compile all from source: libs, program, ...

Comment: Yeah... Thanks. In the meantime, please update your answer to include that I need to install the libraries for the version of wxWidgets that the application was compiled in... I would like to mark your answer as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Manuel

Hi,

You don't have to compile and install the libraries that the program was built with.

When you said that you compiled wxWidgets 3.1.4, does this mean you ran:

```
configure <set_of_options>
make
make install
ldconfig
```

or you just ran:

```
configure
make
```

Now, all different Linux distribution (and Unix ones) have their own repositories. Every *nix distribution have their own way of getting the packages from said distribution. Every *nix distribution works differently with the packages on marking them `stable` inside this distribution in order for the users to do the upgrades.

So for the developers "it is a nightmare" to create different ways to distribute the application on *nix. Therefore *nix developers can create a distribution scripts and/or ask *nix maintainers to include their software in the repository.

That way the distribution script will take care of every dependency the program have. The script will also take care of the needing to upgrade the required library to the newer version - the maintainers of those libraries will have to recompile your software, make sure it works as intended, mark it stable and be done with it. Then they will update the distribution script appropriately.

In the end - it is not your task to distribute on *nix, it is a task of the distribution maintainers to write/update such a distribution script. Or write a proper documentation/example so that you can do it and submit to the distribution maintainers to include it inside their package tree.

I hope it is more clear now.

[EDIT]

Quoting one of your responces from the previous answer:

> At this point, I don't know if it would still be possible to run the
> same app. Since I have the source code and an install of wxWidgets, I
> was able to recompile the binary into a new file and run the program,
> The source code was written and compiled with wxWidgets3.1.3 however I
> have wxWidgets3.1.4 installed and I am not trying to recompile. I am
> only trying to run the binary. If I wanted to run this program on
> another linux install, does this mean that I have to reinstall
> wxWidgets and recompile the program? I am really perplexed. Thank you

[/EDIT]

Comment: 1) I've never said that "have to *compile* and install the libraries that the program was built with". I've said just install; and it those (versions) aren't there, *you can always compile them*. 2) I've never said I compiled anything. 2) OP is not asking for *all different Linux distribution (and Unix ones)*, but just for *Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS and wxWidgets 3.1.4*. 3) We weren't talking about *distributing* software, but about using the correct version. It is a [Github](https://github.com/alvindera97/Engineering-Grade-Pending-C-) repo.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, I have to say that the original repo doesn't have any information about dependencies or version numbers. It only says *All code was written with the Linux operating system, specifically Ubuntu 18.04.04* but didn't say if libraries were changed (versions.) So the *"it is not your task to distribute on _nix"* statement you say, just doesn't make sense. OP is following someone code/program that hasn't *any* kind of quality and *by not means* is ready to distribute. I've just given some advice to work with that software.

Comment: @Manuel, To answer to your points: 1. Yes - that's correct. However you need to know what version the program was built with in order to install them in the first place. 2. No true - see the edit. 3. OK, but in order to produce the binary that will run successfully you need to compile proper version of the wxWidgets, right? And it should be given either in the README.md or in the documentation. Which I agree is incorrect. And as you successfully point out the author of the repository should have taken care of providing a good version or instruct how to upgrade the version.

Comment: Pardon me for the late reply. I am a python guy and this was my first work with C++ so I understand that the code quality is poor. I compiled the code to produce the binary **gpCalculator** with wxWidgets 3.1.3.

Now I have a new install of ubuntu 18.04, I have wxWidgets 3.1.4 installed and I couldn't run the binary. This is the point where I started this question.

Comment: After a bit more question asking on wxWidgets foum: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=47390&p=200108#p200108 , it was explained to me that I could run the binary after I have downloaded wxWidgets source code [the version inwhich the app was built] and built the source [and I apparently don't have to do a `make install`] everything should work...... If I knew about shared in detail, I would most probably not have built wxWidgets with the 'allow-shared-libraries' flag. Yes the application's size would increase, however, no need for extra configuration to get the app to work

Comment: @Alvindera97, keep in mind following 3 points: it is preferrable when working on *nix to build dynamic libraries. 2. Some libraries that you depend on have a license that prohibit static linking. 3. When you build statically and then execute on another machine and that other machine have a copy of the dynamic library of the same software that is incompatible - you will have a crash. And sometimes you will have a crash when they are compatible. Those 2 are the reasons for number 1. And the 2 is most important one - you don't want to be sued.

Comment: @Igor Wow! Thanks! I didn't know of all these. I would report back with the solution that was applicable to the issue. I wish I could select both responses as the answers as they have  been extremely helpful i understanding the entirety of the situations and the different options available....

Thanks so much!
I've learnt a whole lot!