# ImportError when tring to import wxPython

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I am having trouble while using wxPython to build an application. After restarting my system (Ubuntu 22.04) suddenly my application would not work anymore (it did not throw this error prior to restarting) and gives me this Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to search for an answer and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151195/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libwx-gtk3u-core-3-1-so-3-cannot-open-sha) thread, but the version number mentioned in the top ansdwer does not match mine, and I don't know how to install the right version. I tried `sudo apt-get install libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0`, but this did not work.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
After a lot of searching I found the error. When installing from pip it seemas, as wxpython tries to install some gtk version, which did not fit my system. I used

```
pip uninstall wxpython
pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-22.04 wxpython
```

This did install the right version of gtk alongside wxpython for my system (Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: "I tried `sudo apt-get install libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0`": what was the result? Probably a "package not found" or similar error. Have you tried searching for `libwx` first, to see what the package's actual name is? (Probably just `libwx`.)

Comment: How did you try and install wxPython in the first place?

Comment: There was a "package not found error". I looked up all the libwx packets, but  trying 'sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5' did also not yield any success.

Comment: And what about xwPython?

Comment: I used 'pip install wxPython'

Comment: And does `apt search libwx` show anything related already installed?

Comment: @SimonM, try to go to the wxpython.org and download it from there. and the install it on the system.

Comment: Most likely `pip` doesn't knpow where to install modules and so it fails to load...